# Combine and resize many rectangle images into a square image

Tags: php, math, imagick, rectangles

I have some thousands variable products with images. I have to combine 3 or 4 or ... 14 images into one main image what's shape is almost or completely square. I would like to fill the square area as best as possible. So, if necessary, the images can also be resized individually.
The difficulty is that I have to work with different numbers and sizes of images.

I use php and imagick but now I am satisfied with an idea (or a pseudo code or something).

The basic problem:
I have rectangles of different sizes that I want to fill a square with as best as possible without overlap.
The rectangles rotation is not allowed. The resize is allowed one by one.
A secondary requirement is that I would like at least one side of one image should be larger than two-thirds of the edge of the square. And the other rectangles should not be too small.

Example for 5 images:
Image sizes:

1. 1172 x 1250
2. 1211 x 1250
3. 1133 x 1250
4. 1250 x 730
5. 1118 x 1250

One solution:

[image: 5rectangles.jpg]

It doesn't matter how big the final square is.
There are also pictures with completely different proportions, e.g. 353 x 1250, 120 x 1320, 487 x 1220, etc.

I thought about areas and edge lengths, but I couldn't find a solution that can already be used for rectangles of all sizes and numbers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What's the actual problem you have here, though? The easiest way to do this is to _not_ waste time and maths and instead go "if I need five images, my square should have the following areas: ..." and then just put one image into each area, _cropping the image_ as necessary to fit in its space. Because if preserving the original sizes mattered, you wouldn't be mashing them into a single image, just place them and cut off the parts that would overflow =)

Comment: Sorry if I worded it wrongly. The size of the images within the square does not matter, but it is important to keep all images in their original aspect ratio. It is not allowed to cut them.
These are product images in completely different sizes and quantities.
The colored rectangles symbolize the product images in their original proportions.

Comment: what you described is called masonry layout in web design. I'm unfortunately unable to give you a solution in terms of picture transforms to combine in a single picture with the imagick library, but is that the only option?

Comment: I thought about the masonry layout, but it is not limited vertically, I need a square layout. But at the moment I'm also thinking about an arrangement in similar columns and rows. What matters to me is the method, not the specific php or imagick code.